# how to view content of xbase procedures?

Tags: sybase

I would like to view the code of my xbase stored procedures.

I recognize that show procedures gives me the list of procedures.

Can anyone instruct me on how to get the actual code for the stored procedures?

Comment: You question says xbase, but you tagged it Sybase.  Can you please clarify what you are looking for?

Comment: What exactly is xbase?

Answer (score 4):

in Sybase ASE:

- `sp_helptext sp_name` in your database can give you the code of the stored procedure
- `select * from sysobjects where type='P'` in your database can list the stored procedures